# Run global with range from within function

Tags: vimscript, global-command

I have a function somewhat like this:

```
function! MyFunction()
    g/\v.(\n\n|\n*%$)/execute "normal! v{:call AnotherFunction()\<cr>"
endfunction
```

Now I want to be able to pass a range to that function. The problem is… how can I add the range (`a:firstline` and `a:lastline`) before the `g` command?

I tried all the combinations I could think of (like `execute a:firstline.','.a:lastline' 'g/...`), but I can't get it to work (maybe because I already use `execute` in the global command).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation (`:h function-range-example`):

```
function Cont() range
  execute (a:firstline + 1) . "," . a:lastline . 's/^/\t\\ '
endfunction
4,8call Cont()
```

You need to use execute to pass the variables to the `g` command.

In your case, this simplified example should work (at least it works here):

```
function! MyFunction()
    execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline . 'g/^/execute "normal! >>"'
endfunction
1,3call MyFunction()
```

Comment: Ah, you're right, thank you! I wasn't passing a range when calling the function and I assumed it would use the whole file in that case, but apparently it doesn't, so I thought it wasn't working when I tried doing that. Anyway, it's all good now. Thanks again. :)

Comment: Ah, but look, here's a more complicated example that doesn't work, maybe because there are quotes in the pattern: `execute a:firstline . ',' . a:last line . 'g/\(\.\|!\|?\)\()\|]\|"\|'\)*\($\|\s\)/execute "normal! v(:call MyFunction()\<cr>"'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a guess, can you try escaping the `'` with `\'`? (otherwise I think it's worth another question ;) )

Comment: Ok, I had already tried that and it didn't work, but after looking around some more I found out it's possible to escape characters by doing `<c-v><esc>` and then the character. And that works! Edit: wait! no, it doesn't, haha. I'll open another question then.

Comment: I may have a solution if you open the question ;)

Comment: Sorry, I fell asleep. Here it is: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9045/7642 Thank you so much for your help. :)