# Escape quotes within quotes in command

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I'm trying to run a command (from within a function) that goes somewhat like this:

```
execute a:firstline . ',' . a:last line . 'g/\(\.\|!\|?\)\()\|]\|"\|'\)*\($\|\s\)/execute "normal! v(:call MyFunction()\<cr>"'
```

But it doesn't work and I think it's because of all the quotes. I tried escaping them with backslashes, but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying hard to shoot yourself in the foot by doing things this way.  But if you insist: double the `'` in the second group.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I don't insist, I just have no idea what I'm doing, haha. Just changed it to your suggestion on Christian's answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either put the quotes into an extra variable and use that, which saves you from the effort to escape them, or double the single quotes. 
But notes, this makes it really hard to read (and understand) later your regex.

Quote from the help (`:h literal-string`)

> This string is taken as it is.    No backslashes are removed or have a
>   special meaning.  The only exception is that two quotes stand for one
>   quote.

Comment: The regexp could be simplifies like this, I believe: `\v[.!?][])"']*($|\s)`